# Indentation within a do block with infix operator

Tags: haskell

I was reading on [indentation rules](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7) when I stumbled across:

```
y :: [Int]
y = do
  c <- [4, 4, 4]
  return c
  ++ [1]           -- line 5
```

Because of

> if it is indented the same amount, then a new item begins (a semicolon is inserted);

I expected a `;` in front of `++` (on line 5) which should give a parse error but seems to be fine ([example](https://rextester.com/JPSX72996)). This is confusing me.

```
y :: [Int]
y = do{
  ;c <- [4, 4, 4]
  ;return c
  ;++ [1]}         -- I expected a ';' here and thus a parse error
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The paragraph you are quoting starts with:

> Informally stated,

and it is indeed just a quick overview of what is happening, meant to give you some intuition. The formal rules are in section [10.3 Layout](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3).

What happens in your case is that your code gets changed into:

```hs
y :: [Int]
y = do 
  { c <- [4, 4, 4]
  ; return c
  ; ... {- we are here -}
```

the last rule applied being, indeed:

```
L (<n> : ts) (m : ms) = ; : (L ts (m : ms)) if m = n
```

However note that emitting `++` now would cause a parse error, and thus this rule kicks in:

```
L (t : ts) (m : ms) = } : (L (t : ts) ms) if m∕ = 0 and parse-error(t)
                                                        (Note 5)
```

So a closing brace is emitted instead and after that the lexer proceeds normally.

In the end, your code is parsed as:

````
```haskell
y :: [Int]
y = do 
  { c <- [4, 4, 4]
  ; return c
  ; } ++ [1]
````

---

Actually, the overview section mentions this behaviour too (although, admittedly, it is not particularly easy to understand what it says):

> A close brace is also inserted whenever the syntactic category containing the layout list ends; that is, if an illegal lexeme is encountered at a point where a close brace would be legal, a close brace is inserted.